# do i need to filter the OUTPUT with iptables for a dedicated firewall box?

Tags: security, iptables, firewall

I already know how to setup a firewall using `iptables`, but after a visit of the IT Security Department, they said i need to filter the `OUTPUT`, but, it is pointless to me, i really can find an scenario where i need to do that. So, this is my first question:
**do i really need to filter the `OUTPUT`?**
My `OUTPUT` accept all by default and have no rules. Is this a security breach?

They also said i have rules that represent a security breach and i'm not agree with that. Let use this `FORWARD` as example:

```
-P FORWARD DROP
-A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s XX.XX.XX.XX/24 -d XX.XX.XX.XX/32 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

They said accepting `ESTABLISHED` without specifying `source` and `destination` and as the first rule is a **security breach**. Really? Is this another security breach? It is bad practice to `ACCEPT` `ESTABLISHED` without specifying `source` and `destination`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a security perspective the policy is usually *"everything not allowed is to be denied"* and in that regard filtering on the `OUTPUT` chain falls under that blanket policy.

The **`OUTPUT`** chain concerns outgoing TCP/IP packets and connections **originating from the device running iptables** and not the packets passing through the firewall.

An administrator should be aware what the normal usage and intended purpose of a device is and should be able to generate suitable filtering rules for the `OUTPUT` chain as well.

For a firewall that can't be much...
Off-hand I would expect probably DNS, NTP and syslog traffic to specific hosts.

In practice for servers I do not often see filtering on the `OUTPUT` chain, each server just selectively opens up services and filters on `INPUT`, and outgoing traffic is filtered on the border of the network (segments).
The idea being that a host level firewall can also be modified from the host and is therefore not much of a barrier to a malicious administrator nor offers much protection once a host is compromised completely.

Filtering outgoing traffic, i.e. by a firewall on the border of a network that routes (forwards) traffic from "internal" to "external" (and vice versa) is typically called [egress filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egress_filtering) and happens in the `FORWARD` chain, not the `OUTPUT` chain.

Egress filtering is good thing and definitely something you should do.

Comment: Thanks for answering. What about the FORWARD and the ESTABLISHED state doubts?

Comment: An **established connection** is part of a [stateful firewall](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateful_firewall) connection that has already **sucesfully passed all your firewall rules** in the first place. And placing additional constraints on that defeats the whole purpose of having a stateful firewall in the first place. IMHO

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how secure you want to be. Filtering outbound traffic *does* increase security and decrease attack vectors, etc.

Personally, I only filter outbound SMTP (no clients should be connecting to external SMTP servers) and DNS (to prevent I'll effects from malware that changes users' DNS servers to earn external host).

Many orgs have much more restrictive outbound rules, though. If your security department says you need to filter outbound, then you need to filter outbound. Now it's just up to you to work with them to sort out what level of filtering they require.

Comment: Thanks for answering. What about the `FORWARD` and the `ESTABLISHED` state doubts?

Comment: With restrictive INPUT and OUTPUT rules, I dont' see the benefit of matching on source/dest for the ESTABLISHED rule.